# Emojicon Keyboad appears above android keyboard

Tags: android, emoji

Am using Emojicon library and after implementing my layouts and classe, when i click on the smily nutton the Emoji Keyboard gets drawn above the default android keyboard which makes both visible,
I want to hide the keyboard and show only the Emoji Keyboard

Comment: try, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109022/close-hide-the-android-soft-keyboard

Comment: @petey Oh okay let me try